# In Python XlsxWriter How do you set X Axis with dates to be a text axis?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have some weekly time series data which I want to graph. I only want the dates in the time series to appear in the graph, i.e. I don't want Excel to interpolate with empty points for the days between the days in the time series.

I've tried explicitly setting `text_axis` to `True` and `date_axis` to `False` but I end up with an **Automatic** axis and empty points:

[image: Automatic Axis with date data]

If I then manually set the Axis type to **Text** then I get what I'm after:

[image]

This is the code that creates the graph in the first screenshot:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas series with a date index

data = pd.Series([1, 5, 7, 2, 6, 6],
                 index=pd.to_datetime(['2012-10-08',
                                       '2012-10-15',
                                       '2012-10-22',
                                       '2012-10-29',
                                       '2012-11-05',
                                       '2012-11-12']))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Stick it in Excel

worksheet_name = 'test'

df.to_excel(writer, worksheet_name)

# Create a graph

workbook = writer.book
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

chart.add_series({'values': '={worksheet_name}!$B$2:$B$7'.format(worksheet_name=worksheet_name),
                  'categories': '={worksheet_name}!$A$2:$A$7'.format(worksheet_name=worksheet_name)})

# Set the X axis to be a text axis

chart.set_x_axis({'name': 'Week', 'text_axis': True, 'date_axis': False})

# Stick the graph in Excel

sheets = [sheet for sheet in workbook.worksheets() if sheet.name == worksheet_name]
sheets[0].insert_chart('D2', chart)

# Make the date column wide enough for the date to be visible
sheets[0].set_column(0, 0, 20)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This was my bad.

Was on an old version of XlsxWriter in my VirtualEnv.  The module's author John McNamara put me right and it's now working.  Schoolboy error on my part!

```
 pip install --upgrade xlsxwriter
Downloading/unpacking xlsxwriter from https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/X/XlsxWriter/XlsxWriter-0.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=8dca87f0bd21708a0587017c14e5f453
  Downloading XlsxWriter-0.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB): 133kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: xlsxwriter
  Found existing installation: XlsxWriter 0.5.7
    Uninstalling XlsxWriter:
      Successfully uninstalled XlsxWriter
Successfully installed xlsxwriter
Cleaning up...
```